# SSRS show parameter values in header

Tags: expression, ssrs-2008-r2, reportparameter

I am trying to add an expression in header section, which would display parameter value chosen by users (if everything selected, display "ALL" instead).  I am having trouble with "Property" parameter.

Report structure:
Report is a matrix report that shows data by year and grouped by refBuildingID.  Parameter "Property" is based on RefBuildingID.  I want to show these parameter values in header when users run this report.

Expression:

```
=IIF(Countrows("BuildingID")=(Parameters!refBuildingID.Count),"All",Join(Parameters!refBuildingID.Value,", "))
```

Error:
The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox31’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

Is there a way to get around this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

=IIF(Count("BuildingID")=Count(Parameters!refBuildingID.Value),"All",Join(Parameters!refBuildingID.Value,", "))

Comment: I no longer get an error, but now it says "ALL" for any selection I make.

Comment: I see the error, quite rightly so. please attempt this method ("DataSet2" is the initial source of the parameter) =IIF(CountRows("DataSet2").Equals(Parameters!refBuildingID.Count),"All",Join(Parameters!refBuildingID.Value,", "))

Answer (score 0):

i think CountRows will work

```
=IIF(COUNTROWS("BuildingID").Equals(Parameters!refBuildingID.Count),"ALL",Join(Parameters!refBuildingID.Value,", "))
```

Comment: Getting following error when trying your solution: The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox44’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.